# Querying Dynamics 365 for all salesorderdetails associated with a particular salesorder

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm trying to get all `salesorderdetails` associated with a particular `salesorder` by sending a GET request to the following path:

```
$"{orgname}/api/data/v9.1/salesorderdetails?$select=salesorderdetailid&$filter=contains(salesorderid,'{salesOrderId}')";
```

where `salesOrderId` is a sales order GUID as a string in Dynamics 365.
I get the error `No function signature for the function with name 'contains' matches the specified arguments. The function signatures considered are: contains(Edm.String Nullable=true, Edm.String Nullable=true).`

Is this just not the way to go about getting those associated salesorderdetails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax in your case would be:

`$"{orgname}/api/data/v9.1/salesorderdetails?$select=salesorderdetailid&$filter=_salesorderid_value eq {salesOrderId}";`

because `salesorderid` is a lookup.

You can also use my tool [Dataverse REST Builder](https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB) to assist you with the syntax.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, I had used that syntax with the eq filter but was using salesorderid instead of the proper name. Thank you!